# Reactjs, How can I add select option attributes values to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state

I have a small app that has a small form.
the form has these fields:

Course- created mapping over a props object element called courseName

Select- a select field with fixed values.

Course grade- number type field.

In the app state I have two arrays:

1. courses: is the data that creates the form select options
2. newCourse: contains the data that is submitted in the form.

   `state = {
   courses: [
     {
       id: 1,
       courseName: 'English',
       courseType: false,
       courseHours: 10,
       courseGrade: '',
       coursePassGrade: 55
     },{
       id: 2,
       courseName: 'Math',
       courseType: true,
       courseHours: 8,
       courseGrade: '',
       coursePassGrade: 55
     },{
       id: 3,
       courseName: 'Biology',
       courseType: false,
       courseHours: 30,
       courseGrade: 50,
       coursePassGrade: 70
     }
   ],
   newCourses:[]
   }`

I use

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
         [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

in order to update the state with the form field value.

My problem is that I want to add to the `newCourse` state values from the `course` props. I have added this data to the option attributes.
my question is how can I retrieve the option attributes in order to add these values (`courseHours` and `coursePassGrade` see `courses` const bellow) from `course` props to the `newCourse` state 
This is the form component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

class AddCourse extends Component {

    state = {
        courseName: '',
        courseType: '',
        courseGrade: '',
        courseHours: '',
        coursePassGrade: ''
    }

    onChange(e) {
        console.log('e.target', e.target.coursehours);


        this.setState({
             [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addCourse(this.state);
        this.setState({
            courseName: '',
            courseType: '',
            courseGrade: ''
        })
    }
    render() {
        const courses = this.props.courses.map(course =>
            <option 
                key={course.id} 
                value={course.courseName} 
                coursehours={course.courseHours} 
                coursepassgrade={course.coursePassGrade}  
            >
                {course.courseName}
            </option>
        )

        return (
            <div>
                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">

                                <Form.Control
                                    as="select"
                                    name="courseName"
                                    defaultValue={this.state.courseName}
                                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                                >
                                <option value="">Course...</option>
                                    {courses}

                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formGridState">

                                <Form.Control as="select"
                                    name="courseType"
                                    defaultValue={this.state.courseType}
                                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                                >
                                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                                    <option value="true">a</option>
                                    <option value="false">m</option>
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicGrade">
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="number"
                                    placeholder="Course grade"
                                    name="courseGrade"
                                    defaultValue={this.state.courseGrade}
                                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                                />
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Form.Group controlId="courseHours">
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="hidden"
                                    name="courseHours"
                                    defaultValue={this.props.courseHours}

                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group controlId="submit">
                                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                    Submit
                        </Button>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddCourse
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your courses `const` to this:

```
        const courses = this.props.courses.map((course, n) =>
            <option 
                key={course.id} 
                value={n} 
            >
                {course.courseName}
            </option>
        )
```

And your event handler to this:

```
    onChange(e) {
        const { courses } = this.props
        const n = e.target.value
        const { courseName, courseHours, coursePassGrade } = courses[n]
        this.setState({ courseName, courseHours, coursePassGrade, })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct for you, in `App`, to keep the `state` with your list of courses and then with any courses added through the submission of the form.

The `addCourse` handler which you pass from `App` to `AddCourse` should look something like this:

```
// App.js

addCourse = ({ courseName, courseType, courseGrade }) => {

  const { coursePassGrade, courseHours } = this.getCourseByName(courseName)
  const newCourse = {
      courseName,
      courseType,
      courseGrade,
      coursePassGrade,
      courseHours
    }
    const updatedNewCourses = [...this.state.newCourses]
    updatedNewCourses.push(newCourse)
    this.setState({ newCourses: updatedNewCourses })

}
```

In `AddCourse`, when you call the `addCourse` handler, you pass up (to `App`) all of the data that you have from the form (`courseName`, `courseGrade`, and `courseType`). *You do not need to keep track of the corresponding `coursePassGrade` or `courseHours` in your `AddCourse` component.* It can be the job of `App` to find those remaining attributes by searching in his `this.state.courses` based on the `courseName` that he was given.

As you can see from above, this is the job of `getCourseByName`:

```
// App.js

getCourseByName = (courseName) => {

  const index = this.state.courses.findIndex((course) => {
    return (course.courseName === courseName)
  })
  return this.state.courses[index]

}
```

This method looks up (in `this.state.courses`) the course attributes based on the name, and it returns the entire course object. When you call this, in `addCourse`, you only care about the `coursePassGrade` and `courseHours`, which is what you use to continue building the `newCourse` object which will be pushed to `this.state.newCourses`

I have used your code to put together a CodeSandbox which shows these techniques in action. I hope it is helpful to you in giving you some direction.

[image: Edit Course Add - Options and Attributes to State]